# Controller Test problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, testing

I want to test a mvc controller. I'm using Moq to mock the services, but I don't know how to mock this.Request.Files["Attachement1"] and this.Server.MapPath("~/Temp")  ("this" is the controller)

I tried to create a new Mock`<`HttpRequestBase`>`(); but this.Request doesn't have a setter.
Help me please with an advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the folder name resolutions such as: this.Server.MapPath("~/Temp")  I use public properties, and getter returns this so I can easily test it. 
For the Request.Files, I prefer using FormCollection dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as your - I used the set of fake classes from Stephen Walther's blog.

[Asp.Net MVC Tips - Faking the Controller Context](http://www.stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context.aspx)

I had to modify some of the classes slightly but it should do what you want and it's definitely a lot easier to setup than having to mock the entire context every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [TestHelper in the MVCContrib project](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper&referringTitle=Documentation), it can easily be extended to Mock other bits of the Http elements. (It has some Request elements already to use as a template.)

Kindness,

Dan